# Vue Checkbox on Mounted not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, vue.js, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a Vue page that has a checkbox on it that upon mounted I need to read a value from a cookie and check the box if nesscessary. I've noticed that in Edge browser it doesn't correctly get set even though Mounted is definitely called.

I've distilled this problem down to the following smallest example. If you open it up in Edge and hit refresh you should see that sometime its not checked. Where as in Chrome/IE11 it always is.

Any suggestions as to what is causing this and how to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vue / Edge Checkbox Issues</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <p>This checkbox should become checked on mounted. Hit refresh and see what happens in MS Edge.</p>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" v-model="remember">
      <span>Remember Me</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        remember: false
      },
      methods : {
        check () {
          this.remember = true
        }
      },
      // Hooks
      mounted () {
        this.check()
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit:**
I didn't think to mention this... but its worth noting that wrapping the `this.check()` in a `setTimeout` allows it to work, but for me requires the delay to be > 60. So this fixes it, but is obviously really hacky and shouldn't be needed.

```
mounted () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.check()
  }, 120)
}
```

Comment: just tested on edge and it's working well i did a  copy paste of your code even for created method works

Comment: Interesting, any chance you could tell me what your Edge version is?

Comment: Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0 and  Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763

Comment: Thx.. I'm running Microsoft Edge 41.16299.726.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299.... I will test with the new Edge in a VM and see if I still have issues.

Comment: What about `$nextTick`? Does it work?

Comment: No I did try that, both as a callback and a promise.

Comment: I try to test the issue and I notice that for first time check box get checked correctly. Form next time. I noticed that if checkbox is checked and if I refresh the page than it get unchecked. If we unchecked the chekbox manually before refresh than every time it will get checked. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/ZqfqGgLm/121.gif

Comment: humm... that is interesting

Comment: You can try to reset the checkbox may help you to solve the issue for MS Edge browser.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing a little now.

v-model is a short notation for a input event.
But the native checkbox emits a change event when clicked.

If i am right with this then the following should work:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" :checked="remember ? 'checked': '' @change=remember = !remember">
```

Update:
Also change your data part to:

```
data () {
  return {
    remember: false
  }
}
```

Otherwise it could interferre with other instances of that component.

Comment: hmm danke well catch maybe that's the problem

Comment: We actually started with v-bind:checked="..." but chrome would always report the opposite value (if starts unchecked and user clicks checkbox, then the onchange reports false not true, and vise versa). v-model seemed to fix this but not in Edge.

I'll switch it back and see if Edge works with v-bind.

Comment: RE: update... in the actual project it is data() { return {... I was just trying to find the smallest notation to explain the problem. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: For me using v-bind didn't make a difference... <input type="checkbox" name="remember" v-bind:checked="remember ? 'checked': ''"/> didn't work and nor did <input type="checkbox" name="remember" v-bind:checked="remember"/>

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code (I don't have edge to test)?

```
  var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        remember: false
      },
      methods: {
        check: function () {
          this.remember = true
        }
      },
      // Hooks
      mounted: function () {
        this.check()
      }
    })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, same result

Comment: I think IE11 doesn't support the function notation I wrote above. But in our actual project babel compiles the JS down so that it does work in IE11. The snippet I provided was really just to isolate the issue I'm seeing in Edge.